# transforming CASE expression into stored procedure in postgres 14

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm learning function or stored procedures in postgres and wanted to implement one from a `case` expression I have in a sql query.

The sql query is as follows:

```
SELECT current_manu_phase,obsolete_start_date,current_manu_phase_end,
       (CASE
        WHEN CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN (E.OBSOLETE_START_DATE - interval '6 month')::date AND E.OBSOLETE_START_DATE
        AND E.CURRENT_MANU_PHASE = 'Obsolete' THEN 'going to EOS') AS EG_STATUS
FROM EIM E
```

To make a stored procedure out of this `case` block the intention here is to abstract into arguments both the table name and also the interval period which currently into this query is hardcoded as 6 months.

What I've tried:

```
create or replace function get_eg_status(tb text,period text)
returns date
language plpgsql
AS $$
declare res date;
BEGIN
CASE
WHEN CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN (tb.OBSOLETE_START_DATE - interval 'period month')::date AND tb.OBSOLETE_START_DATE
AND tb.CURRENT_MANU_PHASE = 'Obsolete' THEN res := 'going to EOS';
ELSE
END CASE;
END;
$$;
```

The procedure runs fine, no errors. However, when I try to implement into the query by substituting into the sql statement:

```
SELECT current_manu_phase,obsolete_start_date,current_manu_phase_end,
       get_eg_status('eim','6') AS EG_STATUS
FROM EIM E
    
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tb"
LINE 1: CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN (tb.OBSOLETE_START_DATE - interval 'per...
                              ^
QUERY:  CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN (tb.OBSOLETE_START_DATE - interval 'period month')::date AND tb.OBSOLETE_START_DATE
AND tb.CURRENT_MANU_PHASE = 'Obsolete'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_eg_status(text,text) line 4 at CASE
SQL state: 42P01
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think I'm probably interpolating the arguments wrongly inside the begin block or just using incorrectly the function.

Comment: "*the intention here is to abstract into arguments the table name*" - don't. Pass values into the function, not table names. You can pass either `OBSOLETE_START_DATE` and `CURRENT_MANU_PHASE` as two arguments, or you can pass the entire row.

Comment: Also you want to use `language sql` for a simple abstraction like this, not `plpgsql`.

Comment: why not ? tb can be a regclass maybe ? I also need the period as an argument...

Comment: for `language sql` i need to pass `select...` i would like to use a `case` construct that returns many rows in `plpgsql`

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to pass the table name, neither as `text` nor as `regclass`. In `SELECT get_eg_status('eim','6') FROM EIM E`, the expression doesn't even refer to the current row of the table you're selecting from!

Comment: i have two tables that share the same column names, that's why i wanted to pass the table name

Comment: Doesn't matter. You should disambiguate the columns to refer to the value in the same as in every expression. Pass the values, not a name. E.g. `get_eg_status(e.obsolete_start_date, 6, e.current_manu_phase)` or `get_eg_status(e, 6)` or `get_eg_status(eim, 6)`.

Comment: ERROR:  function get_eg_status(eim, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2:        get_eg_status(eim,'6') AS EG_STATUS
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: when using `get_eg_status(eim, 6)`

Comment: I think you should spend some more time with the documentation and its examples. Bergi's advice is good.

Comment: @moth Yes, you need to declare a function that takes a row of type `eim` as a parameter. Not one that takes a string.

Comment: thanks could you hint me about such function ? one that takes a row, thanks